# CSS skew issue - child elements skewing despite opposite skew added

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to get a skewed nav, but the links are skewing with the nav. I understand the code should work if it's like this:

```
#nav {
   transform: skew(-15deg);
}
#nav li {
   transform: skew(15deg);
}
```

But that's not working. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U5mq5/

Again, I want my nav li a to be straight, not slanted. Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#terminology)
>
> A transformable element is an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a block-level or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose display property computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption.

Therefore the display of the elements should be changed from `inline` to `inline-block` in order for `skew()` to work. In addition, I added `white-space: nowrap` in order to prevent the text from wrapping to a new line.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TETNZ/)

```
#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 3.5%;
    transform: skew(15deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(15deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```